# Can't change the position of a gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Was trying to teleport the player to a certain distance. I used `Gameobject.transform.position += new Vector3(0,9,0);` And it seems like it changed position in a very short time and somehow forced back to the previous position so it looks like never moved. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ciZfC.png)

```
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Other)
{
  Debug.Log("Collided");
  if (IsGoingDown)
  {
    Debug.Log("x: " + playerBody.transform.position.x + " y: " + playerBody.transform.position.y);
    playerBody.transform.position = playerBody.transform.position + new Vector3(0,9,0);
    Debug.Log("x: " + playerBody.transform.position.x + " y: " + playerBody.transform.position.y);
    Debug.Log("Going Down");
}
  else
  {
    playerBody.transform.position = playerBody.transform.position + new Vector3(0,-9,0);
    Debug.Log("Going Up");
  }

}
```

Want to know what is forcing the position changed back and how to fix it.

Comment: Are you using a rigidbody on the same gameobject? If so, that might be part of the problem.

Comment: The physics will be applied to the first rigidbody in the object tree. If the rigidbody is on the child, then the child will not affect the parent. However, if the rigidbody is on a parent of the object with your script, then those physics will apply to your object.

Comment: Ambiguous question, put IsGoingDown condition.

Comment: @KiynL IsGoingDown is a boolean that I define on a trigger object. Please look at the screenshot I uploaded, the selected transparent object is the trigger and for this trigger, IsGoingDown is true. So it teleports the player back to the upper stairs.

Comment: @SupaMaggie70b
Thanks for explaining. For this project I didn't use 'rigidbody', I used 'character controller' instead.

Comment: Where is the character controller then?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the infrastructure of other codes and I don't know if it might be a problem, but I think the problem is that when teleporting, the code is executed once again at the second point and the character is directed in the opposite direction.

Use a temporary timer to solve the problem.

```cs
private Coroutine stopTimer;
private IEnumerator TempStop(float timer) // temporary Off the trigger code
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(timer);
    stopTimer = null;
}
private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider Other)
{
    if (stopTimer != null) return;
        
    stopTimer = StartCoroutine(TempStop(.2f));
    
    //....
}
```